# How to assign a value when data type is protocol

Tags: ios, swift

```
protocol PoliceMan {
  func arrestCriminals()
}
struct Person : PoliceMan {
  var toolman : PoliceMan
  func arrestCriminals(){}
  func fixComputer(){}
}
```

I don't know how to assign a name inside about the question3:

1. Declare a struct Person with a name property type String and a protocol name PoliceMan. There is only one method arrestCriminals with no argument and return void in the protocol. Make struct Person conform to PoliceMan protocol.
2. Add a property toolMan to the struct Person with data type PoliceMan
3. Create a Person instance with the name Steven and also create the relative data you need to declare this instance.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what the code should look like for your task:

```swift
// MARK: - Person Model

struct Person {
    let name: String
    let toolMan: PoliceMan
}

// MARK: - PoliceMan Conformance

extension Person: PoliceMan {
    func arrestCriminals() { }
}

// MARK: - PoliceMan Protocol

protocol PoliceMan {
    func arrestCriminals()
}

// MARK: - PoliceMan Conformance

/// Simple struct that exists only so that there is something to instantiate and pass for `toolMan` parameter in `Person(name:, toolMan:)`.
struct SampleToolMan: PoliceMan {
    func arrestCriminals() { }
}


/// Example instance of type `Person`.
let steven = Person(name: "Steven", toolMan: SampleToolMan())
```

You are creating `Person` instance from the synthesized initializer of your struct.